# Remove features with high correlation

Tags: machine-learning, classification, correlation, svm, feature-selection

In a classification problem using Linear SVM, I am trying to remove variables which have a strong correlation (Pearson) between them from a dataset.

- What is the usual threshold recommended? I currently delete variables when they have a correlation >= 1.0 or <= -1.0 but I wonder if I should use 0.5 instead.
- Should I create my correlation matrix after or before scaling the data ?

Comment: Excuse me but how do you have feature that their correlation is greater than 1? Deleting perfectly correlated features is quite reasonable but how do you get the $>$ of your heuristic? Do you somehow calculate variances and then you normalize them? In any case regrading your second question the correlation is not relevant to the scaling of your data so that should not make any difference.

Comment: How are you determining which variable to remove in case of high correlation?

Comment: Keep in mind that the linear correlation coefficient only detects **linear** correlations. Depending on what problem you're trying to solve (unstated in the post), this additional pre-processing may not even do anything helpful.

Comment: @usεr11852 I don't have correlation greater than 1. I just used >= and <= so that I can change the number by another value and my condition still works in the code. Sorry if this was misleading.

Comment: @JasonMorgan for now I don't have a real procedure. I just take one of the two correlated variables.

Comment: @user777 after some test, it looks like it does not improve my classification. However it removes a lot of variables so the model is slightly faster to train.

Comment: @Octoplus Assuming you have a method of deciding which variable to remove, you could always use cross-validation to choose the threshold. Of course, you could also use CV to choose which variable to remove, if you really want to go that route.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think you should look into ever very high correlation pair (say, $|\rho}$ > 0.90) if possible and see what is going on; @JasonMorgan touched on a very important issue. I think we need a bit more context to give better suggestions (and a real answer possibly). As it stands one can say that a usual threshold is usually around ~0.7 (eg. in Tabachnick & Fidell (2006)); actually though you don't mind this multicollinearity much because you care more about predictions which as you say based on cross-validation, they do not change a lot.

Comment: My answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/264016/why-lasso-or-elasticnet-perform-better-than-ridge-when-the-features-are-correlat/264118#264118 is relevant

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be answered in the abstract, we would need to know what is the goal, and what is the variables. Some possibilities:

Two variables which basically are different measurements of the same thing with independent errors. Then keep both (or use their mean) looks reasonable. Other cases are less clear-cut. Since you have a classification problem, the following is relevant: [Feature Selection: Correlation and Redundancy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/242792/feature-selection-correlation-and-redundancy)  even highly correlated variables could have non-redundant information, and in the example given removing any of them would destroy its information content. But, interestingly, in that example replacing the two variables with their *difference* would work! That underscores that each example have to be treated on its own. Some general threshold value which would always work would be difficult to find!

Answer (score 0):

There is no **one-size-fits-all** solution for this. The threshold could be judged by the researcher based on the association between the variables.

For the high correlation issue, you could basically test the collinearity of the variables to decide whether to keep or drop variables (features). You could check Farrar-Glauber test (F-G test) for multicollinearity. Here is a link to do it in R for example: https://www.r-bloggers.com/multicollinearity-in-r/

For the scaling issue, the scaling (if you mean multiplication of variables by a real number), it does not affect the linear relationship across variables. It is however recommended to scale the features for SVM if you are using Euclidean distance metric as kernel.