# Feature Selection: Correlation and Redundancy

Tags: time-series, correlation, classification, data-preprocessing

Assume having several numerical, multidimensional time-series. As preprocessing of further Analysis, I firstly check for **relevance** and then for **redundany** of all dimensions/Features.

1) Check for relevance:
I will exclude all dimensions with a variance of 0 over the whole dataset - since this specific Dimension does not contain Information that helps to classify/distinguish the time-series from each other.

2) Check for redundancy:
I compute the correlation of all dimensions/Features with each other and my Intuition says (**here is my question**) that those Features-pairs which correlate by either -1 or +1 are redundant. Whereas a high correlation such as 0,99 seems to be redundant, it is not. Only a correlation of either -1 or +1 means redundancy. 
Therefore i will randomly exclude on the two dimensions/Features which correlate by +1 or -1.

I am yet sceptical whether or not this is a correct assumption. Are there any leads that could prove / disproves my intuiton of the Connection between redundancy and correlation?

Answer (score 3):

High absolute correlation does **not** imply redundancy of features in the context of classification.

An example is given in the textbook [Feature Extraction - Foundations and Applications](http://www.springer.com/de/book/9783540354871) by I. Guyon et al. (p.10, figure 2 (e))
I reproduced the example for visualization with matplotlib and in Python.

[image]

In this example both features correlate highly, yet seperation of classes will only be achieved if both features are used. Therefore correlation does not imply redundancy.

Comment: Interesting example, but these variables do not correlate with $r=1$. An example of two observations is $(6,5), (7,5)$.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know what kind of analysis you are doing with the data. What questions are you trying to answer? This would help you come up with a better threshold for correlations.

When I do classification work with data, I typically filter correlations higher than 0.85 because high correlation variables are not giving a whole lot of new information for my classification problem. As with any thresholding problem, there is a lot of subjectivity involved. Whatever threshold you pick you need to justify. (This is why knowing what kind of analysis you are doing would be important for choosing a threshold)

Comment: What I want to do is outlier detection. The threshold I consider is 1. I am wondering whether there is a General theory of Information Content and correlation. Does a correlation of 1 ( or -1) really indicate that all Information contained in two time-series could be represented by only one of them?=